# Laptop hard drive loses power after connecting all USB ports

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, usb, hardware-failure, io

[Win 10] Recently my MSI GS60 Ghost Pro-002's secondary Hard Drive has been losing power (I think?) seemingly randomly. However, I am 90% sure it is not an issue with the hard drive, because the only fix to get the BIOS to detect the drive is to literally take it out from the sata and power connector and then re-seat it, which makes me think it is another hardware issue.

When I plug the drive back in the laptop loads it normally. No Errors, and the drive is healthy. I have scanned it with multiple hard drive scanners.

My laptop boots completely normally and functions correctly without the hundreds of games and work on the 2nd drive.

I have done some troubleshooting, and it seems like plugging or unplugging all of my USB devices causes this. I have 5 USB devices and 6 USB connectors that are split the following way:
1. Keyboard: Connects to my monitor, then an extension USB-B to USB-A runs from the monitor to one of my 2 USB 3.0 ports.
2. The other USB 3.0 port is used by a 4-way USB hub which connects my mouse, keypad, external fan, and headphones.

I also connect an Ethernet cable and Display-port cable.

I have checked Event Viewer, and I receive the following errors. I had to split up the error log into 2, because there are about 1,000 type disk event-51 errors in between the head and tail.
head: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yllxjjkxry4i0cf/head.evtx?dl=0
tail: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xoz30lf98plxvx/tail.evtx?dl=0

I would really appreciate any troublshooting tips and any information on what I can do, as I can't keep opening the laptop and reseating the hard drive.

Comment: Does pulling the battery while not on AC power have the same effect as pulling the drive?

Comment: @Twisty do you mean removing the battery while the laptop is powered on (without ac)?

Comment: @Twisty I can't open the hood right now, but I did reset the battery with the battery reset pinhole on the side of the laptop. Assuming this is the same as what you suggested, it had no effect.

Comment: No, I do not mean removing the battery while it's powered on. Shut down normally, then remove the battery for a few minutes. (I also don't mean resetting the battery through the pinhole).

Comment: I've been able to narrow it down to a dying battery @Twisty without taking anything apart :)

Comment: Sorry for the spam, but another question: should the drive receive power when the laptop is powered by AC only (with the battery removed from the system)?. The drive is no longer recongized by the BIOS no matter what I do. @Twisty

Comment: Yes, everything should have power even if the battery has been removed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57278/discussion-between-eoin-fitzpatrick-and-twisty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've solved my problem. Even more recently (more recent than the noticeable hard drive power drops) my laptop has been shutting off on battery power while it still has a significant amount of charge. Also, the battery drains extremely fast, where I can actually tell that it is draining.

It's gotten so bad that a quick battery life report shows pretty terrible results for its capacity:
[battery capacity chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEICA.png). (Left column is actual capacity, right is designed capacity) The sudden drop in capacity correlates to when the hard drive started acting up. Looks like I'll have to order a new battery. Luckily it's not anything broken on the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify whether or not, if your USB hub isn't powered, it's possible you're drawing too much power from your laptop and for whatever reason your laptop is triaging it by killing power to your internal drive. I would suggest trying a powered USB hub to see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: The hub is not powered. I wouldn't think that would matter when the laptop is on AC power though. Also, this is a recent issue, i have used the hub for a while without my issue.